# Isn't paying a mining fee in Ethereum similar to paying a fee to banks?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, bitcoin

One of the main goals of a blockchain is to get rid of the middle men and not having to pay a fee to the middlemen like the banks but here we pay a mining fee to the miners.

Comment: There is a transaction fee, but not a mining fee. Also what 'bank fee' are you referring to? The account management charge? Be specfic in your question. The question in its current form is to broad and invites discussion.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not programming related. It belongs on https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are somehow right. But in the normal banking system you cannot be a part of that middle man pool. In banking system only bank is the centralised system to charge there customers/users and you dont know whats happening in there centralised system. You yourself can't decide the fee. But on the other hand in blockchain system you are actually not paying fee to a centralised authority but to the network and you can also be a part of that network/mining pool and start earning too. Blockchain system is transparent and you cannot question the authenticity of the transactions being done within the network.

Comment: But with mining pools like btc having 22.6% of hashing power arent they after a point become the bank because they already have systems that allow the person to pay them externally in usd and then get their transaction picked first

Comment: Banks hold your money. Mining pools doesnt hold your money/Crypto. They get there share for some work they do that is mining. In Banks you cannot go there and ask that i would also like to sit in your bank and start collecting money from others or get fee from other. In public blockchain you yourself can also be a miner...

Comment: and i think you are taking about exchanges here. You give money/usd to exchanges in order to get cryptos. I dont know much btc but in ethereum you give gas price to get your transaction done first and you give that to network and then there is a competiton between the miners who solve the riddle first get the rewards...